# javascript is not working from asp.net to change simple label text

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have been through 4hrs of posts now. I can not get this js code to work.  This is the latest iteration, I have tried many combinations.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebFormRedisTest.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function updateText(strData) {
        debugger;
        document.getElementById("<%=lbl.ClientID%>").innerHTML(strData);
    }

</script> 
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Test_OnClientClick"/>

        <div>
        </div>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="Label" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

public void Test_OnClientClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "updateText", "updateText('test');", true);
        }
```

Comment: Open the devtools of your browser and check for error messages in the console. Also check whether the generated JavaScript is what you expect

Comment: can you share more details about question, what are you trying to do?

Comment: sorry i thought it was obvious that i'm just trying in this simplified version to change the text of a label via js.  I know it's something simple as i've done this before but can't get the syntax correct, it is just not working to change label text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think innerHTML() is a function. I think you have to write something like:

```
document.getElementById("<%=lbl.ClientID%>").innerHTML = strData;
```

### Update:

I started a quick webforms project and this is what my script tag section looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function updateText(strData) {
        debugger;
        document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML = strData;
    }

</script>
```

The back-end is just like yours.

```
public void Test_OnClientClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "updateText", "updateText('test');", true);
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to change the text of the label specifically, you probably need to use "document.getElementById().innerText =". I've just used both innerHTML and innerText and they both work for me.